# Create accordion menu with TypoScript

Tags: menu, typo3, accordion, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Yesterday and today I had quite some fun figuring out how to create an accordion menu with bootstrap css and TypoScript in TYPO3 7.6.*

Since I nearly lost my mind and questioned my brain on the way to it, I am searching for a good solution.

Edit: moved solution to own answer and changed topic start to question

Comment: You should reformat this as a self-answered question - the way it currently is it'll be closed (because it's not a question).

Comment: Maybe add it as an example to the documentation?

Comment: How can I reformat this as self-answered question? Besides that, I am sure there is room for improvement to my solution!

Comment: Edit your question so it contains an actual question, and then take your solution, and make an answer from it. When editing the question, make sure to leave an appropriate comment so your review passes the edit reviews (not sure if edits to own questions are reviewed though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday and today I had quite some fun figuring out how to create an accordion menu with bootstrap css and TypoScript in TYPO3 7.6.*

Since I nearly lost my mind and questioned my brain on the way to it, I want to share you my outcome and would like to get some improvement ideas.

I have a 2 level menu where the first level is only for grouping - not linked - and the second level contains the sub pages

This is the HTML container inside my template:

```
# HTML part, put into your template
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.menu2" />
</div>
```

And this is my TypoScript:

```
# TypoScript part
lib.menu2 = HMENU
lib.menu2 {
  wrap = |

  1 = TMENU
  1.expAll = 1

  1.NO = 1
  1.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="panel panel-default">| </table></div></div></div>
  1.NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
  1.NO.allStdWrap.dataWrap =  <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{field:uid}"> | </a></h4></div><div id="collapse{field:uid}" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"><table class="table">

  1.IFSUB < .1.NO
  1.IFSUB.allStdWrap.dataWrap =  <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{field:uid}"> | </a></h4></div><div id="collapse{field:uid}" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body"><table class="table">

  1.CURIFSUB < .1.NO
  1.CURIFSUB.allStdWrap.dataWrap =  <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{field:uid}"> | </a></h4></div><div id="collapse{field:uid}" class="panel-collapse collapse in"><div class="panel-body"><table class="table">
  1.ACTIFSUB< .1.CURIFSUB

  2 = TMENU
  2.NO = 1
  2.NO.linkWrap = <tr><td> | </td></tr>
}
```

I still a small clean up on my todolist, to remove the submenu stuff for NO where there is no submenu.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use fluid for Menu rendering. Here are some examples:

https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/tree/master/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Menu

Comment: omg, this has not come to my mind and is so much smarter than hacking TS. I can see templates for fluid only, do you know if I need to include something into my TS to have the variable available? For example this one here: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Menu/Directory.html needs `pageUids` to render a list of pages

Comment: <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>

Answer (score 0):

@firegate666, your solution was inspirational! I've modified to account for:
- subparts (note: also works with fluid, just change ###SUBPART### )
- user-generated full CSS styling (no panels)
- a (minimum) 3 level menu

HTML Template:

```
 <!-- ###MENU### START -->

 <!-- ###MENU### END -->
```

TYPOscript:

```
# declare the menu,
# wrap it in a list <ul>
# and then wrap all that in a container div (for post-processing menus like slicknav),
subparts.MENU = HMENU
subparts.MENU.wrap = <div id="menu"><ul> | </ul></div>
subparts.MENU {

    # 1st level
    1 = TMENU
    1 {

      expAll = 1

      # enable the NOrmal state, wrap it in a <li>
      NO = 1
      NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>


      # IF item has a SUBmenu, then it's still like a NOrmal item, but more
      # wrap it in Bootstrap accordion/collapse functionality
      # then close it
      IFSUB < .NO
      IFSUB = 1  
      IFSUB.allStdWrap.dataWrap (
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{field:uid}"> | </a>
        <div id="collapse{field:uid}" class="collapse">
          <ul>
      )
      IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub (
            <li> | </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
      IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1

    }

    # 2nd level sub-menu and 3rd level sub-sub-menu inherit all the properties of 1st level
    2 < .1
    3 < .1


# end subparts.MENU
}
```

...and (suggested) CSS:

```
.accordion-toggle:before {
  content: "- ";
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed:before {
  content: "+ ";
}
```

I hope this addition to your code is helpful :-)